# Stuck on booting after machine is added to MAAS

Tags: boot, server, maas

Recently I encountered an issue on MAAS.
I have a new node, after rebooting, it shows up on MAAS. Then I ran commission and the node powered off correctly.
I then power on the machine, I don't want to deploy and wipe it yet. However the machine is stuck on booting page with the following error:

Loading centos/amd64/generic/centos70/no-such-image/boot-kernel...failed: No such file or directory

Anyone know what caused this error and how to skip it? Thanks!

MAAS version: 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you must first add the specific images to your cluster, it seems it is looking for 64bit centos however there is not any image in your cluster!

Go to images of your MAAS and select Centos image to be downloaded!

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I have verified Centos image is already downloaded to the MAAS server. Not sure why it is still complaining